# Isolation level Read_Committed is not working

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to test isolation `Read_Committed`. I added Propogation.Required for outer transaction and isolation Read_Committed for my inner transaction. But before committing the outer transaction I am able to fetch record. Below is my code

```
@Service
public class CustomerManagerImpl implements CustomerManager {

@Autowired
private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

public void setCustomerDAO(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
    this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
}

@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void createCustomer(Customer cust) {
    customerDAO.create(cust);
}

@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public void createAddress(Address add) {
    customerDAO.createAdd(add);

}
//@Transactional
@Transactional(isolation =Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void findCustomer(int id) {
customerDAO.findCustomer(id);

}
```

helper class for outer transaction :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)

public void saveObject() {
    Customer cust = createDummyCustomer();
    customerManager.createCustomer(cust);
    customerManager.findCustomer(2);
    Address add =createDummyAddress();
    customerManager.createAddress(add);
}
```

Comment: There is no inner and outer transaction. There is just a single transaction wrapping the whole of  `saveObject`. You can always see changes inside your own transaction.

Comment: public void saveObject() {
  Customer cust = createDummyCustomer();
  customerManager.updateCustomer(2);
  customerManager.findCustomer(2);
 } ..why method findCustomer(2) is fetching commited data before committing to database ? Even If I am changing isolation level READ_UNCOMMITTED then also m getting same record...that means data is always fetching from pojo or may some jdbc session

Comment: You aren't changing anything... The `@Transactional` annotation don't do anything because there is already an ongoing outer transaction. So there are no inner/outer transaction there is only 1 single transaction.

Comment: hey M. Deinum... can u give me one small example on inner and outer transaction

Comment: and also my question was related to isolation level Read_Commited.

Comment: I know what your question is about, but the isolation level only has meaning between transactions. As you don't have multiple transactions (there is only 1) it doesn't matter because you can always see your own changes in the same transaction. If you want multiple transactions one of inner methods would need a different propagation level `REQUIRES_NEW` then it will create a new transaction.